# Accessing gridview row data CONSISTENTLY from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have an asp.net webpage that contains a gridview with SQL data bound to it using the DataSourceID property.  I want to be able to launch JavaScript from various user events (like button clicks and row clicks in a second gridview) and use JavaScript to read the gv1 data and perform some simple actions.  My problem is, some of my JavaScript calls see the data in the gridview, but many times all I see in the gridview is a header (no rows of data!).

For example, if I put a call to JavaScript inside Page_Load() using

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Page.GetType, "Script", "jsPageLoadFirst();", True)
```

then I always see the gridview data on the initial page load, and also on some postbacks.  On other postbacks however the gridview has been stripped and all I see is the gridview header (rows are undefined).

Similarly, if I setup a call to JavaScript in the html body as

```
<body id="mybody" onload="JavaScript:myJSsub();">
```

the JavaScript sub never sees the gridview data; only the header, but no rows.  I THOUGHT that the client onload event only occurred after the page was fully loaded (including all data binding!) but apparently not!  Note that I always see the gridview data showing on the webpage, even right before I click a button to invoke JavaScript, so it's a mystery to me as to why the gridview data sometimes gets stripped!

I've been pulling my hair out for days trying to figure this one out.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, and how I can make sure the gridview row data is always available to my JavaScript subs, no matter where (or how) I launch them?

Thanks!

-tom

10/7 update:  Here's a little bit more info, plus a possible work around I've come up with today using a hidden field.  First, I'm primarily accessing the gridview data in JavaScript using calls to `document.getElementById("gv1")`.  So to start things off, since all the gridview data is available to the JavaScript sub I fire from the first server PageLoad event, I tried saving the gridview data in both a global variable "gvar1" and also in a hidden field on my page "hf1".  Here is what my JavaScript looks like:

```
    function jsPageLoadFirst() {
        // Save gv1 to a global variable
        gvar1 = document.getElementById("gv1");

        // *** Also save gv1's html to a hidden field
        document.getElementById("hf1").value = document.getElementById("gv1").innerHTML;
    }
```

Now in the JavaScript sub I trigger from the onload() event of the body, I check the values of all three.  I always find that 1) `document.getElementById("gv1")` shows only the gridview header (but no rows), 2) `gvar1` is undefined and 3) `hf1` looks fine - all row data is present.  Similarly when firing javascript from server Postback pageloads, sometimes `document.getElementById("gv1")` shows all the gridview data, but sometimes it only shows the gridview header but no row data.  Can someone explain to me why `document.getElementById("gv1")` does not always show the row data?  I think if I understood this, I could see my way clear to get the rest of my code working.  Thanks!!!

Comment: You try putting your `RegisterStartupScript` line in the GridViews DataBound event?

Comment: No, I wouldn't want to fire any client code while responding to the row databound event.  I do set the onclick attribute of the gridview cells in the databound event so that I can take action later when a gridview cell is clicked, but the problem I'm having doesn't seem to me to be related to this.  I have the problem regardless of whether I click the gridview cell.  I added a little more info today to maybe clarify what exactly my problem or misunderstanding is.  Thanks.